# How can I put an each item of an array of checkboxes in each row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website where I select multiple checkboxes and I want to save the selected ones in different rows in table in database. With this method below I save all the array in just one row. How do I save them in different rows?

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("fazer") or die(mysql_error());

$variavel = $_POST['color'];

$checkBox = implodefor(',', $variavel);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
    $query="INSERT INTO fazer (fazer) VALUES ('" . $checkBox . "')";     

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );

    echo "Complete";

}

?>
```

Comment: `implodefor()` isn't a core php function; where's your custom function for it?

Answer (score 1):

You have (it's simpler) to leave them has an array to do that:

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("fazer") or die(mysql_error());

$variavel = $_POST['color'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    

    foreach($variavel as $var) {
        $query="INSERT INTO fazer (fazer) VALUES ('" . $var . "')";     
        mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
    }
    echo "Complete";

}
```

I don't really understand what is `implodefor`

Comment: Thanks!! you really helped me. Implode was for joining everything in just one String(I was thinking wrong). I am new to PHP sorry for my lack of knowledge :)